# Formalizing programmers errors

Tags: productivity, bug

Every one of us make errors leading to bugs. Once I wanted to start logging my errors for future analysis, probably mentioning project title, approximate time spent and the most important, the type of error. For example when I copy-pasted a fragment about 'x' and replaced every occurrence of 'x' with 'y' and forgot to replace a tiny piece, this goes to 'copy-paste error'. The usefulness of this approach depends on whether I can formalize my errors at all and probably minimizing the number of types to choose from. Otherwise I would start postponing, ignoring and so on so make this system useless.

Are there existing research in this area, probably a known minimum set of errors? Maybe some of you already tried to implement something like this and succeeded/failed?

Comment: Sounds like a bug/issue tracker.  Plenty of those.

Comment: Partly yes, but the main part of the one I described is the information added after not before it's been fixed. The tracker goal is not to forget some bug exists, but I want to track why the bug is appeared

Comment: This makes not sense. How would you know if it was a copy&paste error, or something else? btw you shouldn't be doing copy&paste in your code ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Comment: @VJovic When I finally fixed the bug, I know why it is here. This moment of truth is when I see the lines: x=x+xshift;y=y+xshift. I change the second xshift to yshift and add a record about "copy-paste error"

Comment: @Maksee That means you are not doing unit tests. A simple unit test would catch that error.

Comment: no problem, taxonomy like this will allow presenting for example a table when columns explains different relation to particular bug for example "avoidable with unit testing", "applicable to imperative languages", "applicable to functional languages" and so on

Comment: You might also want to track time of day of entering that code.  Maybe typos are more common during one part of the day, and logic errors (etc.) during another?

Comment: @hotpaw2. Thanks, I like this idea. Although this would require full revision system to track the time of entering the defect code.

Comment: If you want to increase your productivity at your bug collection process, you might want to try some scotch or vodka before each coding session.

Comment: A decrease in bug-rate for a beginner is probably a sign if improvement, for an experienced one, it may be a sign of not challenging yourself. Assuming they're not the same type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy) of software bugs. Here are several of such taxonomies:

- http://cs.nyu.edu/~lharris/content/bugtaxonomy.html
- http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/05/01/taxonomy-of-software-bugs/
- http://www.mcr.org.in/sureshmudunuri/stm/unit1.php#bug_taxonomy

Here's even a [thesis paper](http://www.testingeducation.org/a/bugtax.pdf) of someone who surveyed 26 different bug taxonomies.

You'll probably find that each taxonomy is a little different, with different categories, different levels of detail, and even completely different basic concepts.

I wouldn't worry too much about what categories to choose exactly, or what category to assign individual bugs too. It seems like a rather useless exercise in futility to aim for a perfect categorization of something as varied as software bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the links. As for usefulness, I thought that at least I can find my personal mental "hit" for bugs and improve my habits for fixing it. Or when some bug appeared, I would already know the probabilities of my own bugs so think of most frequent reasons first.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at Brain Hayes' [Debugging Myself](http://bit-player.org/bph-publications/AmSci-1995-09-Hayes-Debugging-myself.pdf).  I'm not sure that he started out with error categories, or just determined them as time goes on.

I think this is an inherently difficult area.  What do you classify as an error? I personally wouldn't classify a typo as an error, but if you're doing Personal Software Process, I'm pretty sure that you do classify misspelled key words as an error.

Comment: Very interesting view from the side of the user. Actually he lacks the information I need, but nevertheless does a good job )

Answer (score 4):

I would say that, if you want to understand your own programming errors, you would need to think about what matters to you.  I personally think of my programming errors in the following categories:

1. **Clerical errors**. Examples are typo's, calling the wrong functions/methods, getting the order of arguments wrong etc.  Typically compilers and type checkers catch such errors, or a simple exercising of the code does.
2. **Misunderstandings of the program**.  I may not have a full understanding of the program (or its components, classes, libraries or whatever), or misunderstood them, and wrote the wrong code that doesn't fit.  Usually these errors are caught by the first few cycles of routine testing.
3. **Misunderstandings of the requirements**.  I was supposed to do X but did Y.  Either I didn't understand the requirements fully or misunderstood them.  These are caught by the first few cycles of user testing.
4. **Logical flaws**.  These are the biggies.  Assuming I understood everything correctly, I still ended up writing the wrong code.  These are *not simply "human" errors*.  I was either lazy, didn't think things through carefully, used the wrong algorithms or data structures that didn't fit, the problem was too hard and complicated and I didn't put enough effort into doing it right, or perhaps I wasn't up to the task.  These are usually not caught by routine testing and go into deployment.  Big problem.  Every time I get one of these, I think long and hard about how to avoid such a thing in future.
5. **Design flaws**.  Used the wrong data structure, wrong interfaces, wrong program structure or whatever.  These things don't affect the program behaviour, but affect future development.  They result in a brittle system that can't be extended or modified easily, result in more and more bugs of the previous kinds over a period of time, or simply result in a structure that I am not proud of.  Some amount of painful and tedious refactoring is needed to fix these problems.  Every time I get one of these, I learn something new and deep about the nature of programming.

Answer (score 3):

The [Personal Software Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_software_process) emphasizes a lot of these things.  Improving quality and estimation by keeping logs of the past/present.  I recommend looking at [sample forms](http://www.ipd.uka.de/mitarbeiter/muellerm/PSP/#forms) for ideas.

Comment: Very interesting. PSP has only 10 defect types and this looks promising to be easily remembered and located

Comment: 10 defect types initially, and a key step in the process is the PIP - process improvement proposal which lets you evolve the process over time as you learn more about yourself and the way you code.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers concern software bug causes in terms of human errors by the coder.  There's lots of research into human errors in safety critical human operator areas, such as aviation pilot errors by the FAA and NTSB.  There's also research into human memory and perceptual fallibility that might be applicable.

Unit testing is like the stall warning going off after the pilot has already approached a dangerous flight regime.  A personal study of how not to create, or how to minimize, code that produces results for unit tests to find and fail seems at minimum interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to a very limited degree:

> I had a production application with a lot of live users. The system had an in-built error logger. During critical errors, it would send detailed email reports.

Since everything was logged it was possible to see trends, and allowed developers to focus on different areas (sometimes ones we would not normally concentrate on).

**SO**

A more automated approach would be better.

*Perhaps you could create a an application that can log and analyse compiler errors and cross reference them with Source control logs along with automatic error reports from live applications?*